# node.js: building msnodesql fails

Tags: node.js, windows-8, sql-server-2012

I want to connect from node.js to an MSSQL on Windows8 but I can´t get it working :(

if I run `node-gyp configure build`

I get this ERROR

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\mkirchweger\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Users\\mkirchweger\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_mod
ules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Bibliotheken\node_test\node_modules\msnodesql
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.18
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok
```

If I try to run my node.js app without the build of course I get the Message

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/sqlserver.node'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should preface that the node.js module "Node-sqlserver" was renamed "MSNodeSQL".

I was able to find the changes required by going to the modules github at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/tree/master/src

At the link above, the change is outlined under Operation.h

Change to from (line 38):

```
int result = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &operation->work, OnBackground, OnForeground);
```

To:

```
int result = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &operation->work, OnBackground, (uv_after_work_cb)OnForeground);
```

I hope this answer is sufficient.